# Chef 12: Error while uploading cookbook

Tags: chef

I am using Chef and trying to upload a cookbook on chef-server but getting an error in response:

> {"error":["Invalid key all_files in request body"]}

However, I can see the list of cookbook using `knife node list`

My chefDK version:

```
chef -v
Chef Development Kit Version: 2.0.28
chef-client version: 13.2.20
delivery version: master (17c1b0fed9be4c70f69091a6d21a4cbf0df60a23)
berks version: 6.2.0
kitchen version: 1.16.0
inspec version: 1.31.1
```

Chef-server version is `12.0.5`

Logs:

```
DEBUG: Response body contains:
{"error":["Invalid key all_files in request body"]}
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONInput#handle_response
```

I can't upload more logs, if one needs particular info then I can provide.

Any help?

Comment: Give a full log and the command involved, the tools version and chef-server version you're using, but that would be better suited on [chef's slack](http://community-slack.chef.io/) for assistance than this site as this is likely to fade out in usefulness quickly.

Comment: Hi @Tensibai I have updated the question on you suggestion

Comment: Probably related [github issue](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/6273)

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to have been answered in the [Chef issue](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/6273). To close the loop, I will summarise it here:

This was a bug introduced in Chef 12:

> The issue is with `chef_solo` vs `chef_zero`. It seems `chef_solo` was the old way of doing Chef things. So I added `chef_zero.enabled true` in the `knife.rb` file to activate `chef_zero` instead of `chef_solo`. When you do this, you should be able to upload.

It was [subsequently fixed](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/6273#issuecomment-326289442) in Chef 13:

> This is fixed in Chef 13.3.3, which will be released in the ChefDK 2.2 release

At the time of writing, Chef is in major version 15, so this issue is very unlikely to be encountered in the wild.